# SCOM 2012 Windows Service Monitoring Target object

Tags: powershell, scom

How can I find name of group targeted a windows service monitor which created with template using Powershell?

I mean, I created a monitor in scom using template, I am checking a service. I targeted the monitor to a group. I want to find group name with Powershell.

[image: You can look this image]

I wants to get target information on windows service template. How can I get this using Powershell?

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the target ID for 'All Windows Computers' , execute `$targetID = Get-SCOMClassInstance -Class (Get-SCClass | Where-Object DisplayName -Like 'All Windows Computers') | Select ManagementPackClassIds`.

Then use the target ID to query  ' Get-SCOMMonitor | Select-Object -First 1 | where-object DisplayName -eq 'Queries With High Fetches' | where-object Target -like 'ManagementPackElementUniqueIdentifier=$targetID*'` and see what you get. This is just how you could go about it. Please note that you might have to perform the some string interpolation to get this to work with $targetID.